# Why is my keypress and style.colour not working (but keypress and playAudio working fine)?

Tags: javascript

Here is how I intended it to go: The buttons can be pressed either by:

- clicking on them using the mouse OR
- pressing certain keys on the keyboard keys.

And they are supposed to:

- make a sound
- the button innerHtml (meaning the words on it) will change colour

However now, when the mouse is used to click, both sound and colour change work fine. But when keyboard is used, sound works but **colour does not change**. I have no idea why...please help and thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
// Detecting keydown

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  makeSound(event.key);
  var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  this.style.color = "orange"
})


// Detecting clicks

for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.style.color = "orange"
        makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
    }
  );
}

// makeSound
function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kickbass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickbass.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `keydown` event, `this == document`, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

In an event listener, `this` will be set to the element that the listener was attached to, not the element that was clicked on. Use `event.target` to get the button you clicked on.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  //makeSound(event.key);
  var button = event.target;
  var buttonInnerHTML = button.innerHTML;
  button.style.color = "orange"
})
```

```html
<button>Type here</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped `this.target` should be `event.target`.

Comment: It still doesn't work I actually am reading about event.target now